# Where is the ExpressJS documentation?

Tags: express

For instance, this is a sample of what is created after typing the `express` command:

```
app.set 'port', process.env.PORT or 3000
app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
app.set 'view engine', 'jade'
app.use express.favicon()
app.use express.logger 'dev'
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()
app.use app.router
app.use express.static path.join __dirname, 'public'
```

(converted into CoffeeScript that is).

But visiting http://expressjs.com reveals no documentation for any of this.  'views'?  'views engine'?  express.bodyParser()?  Where is all this?

It's not at any of these locations:

- http://expressjs.com/api.html
- http://expressjs.com/faq.html
- http://expressjs.com/guide.html

The little amount of documentation that exists is next to useless:

```
app.set(name, value)
Assigns setting name to value.
```

What is this I don't even...

Maybe I'm missing something obvious?  I'm not looking for tutorials; they only give you part of the picture -- I want an official, comprehensive overview.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the ExpressJS folks just switched to the 3.x version of the docs which look pretty spare.  I can't find the 2.x docs I was used to.

Comment: I'm slowly figuring things out by examining source code and piecing bits of documentation together, but this is probably the worst documentation for a framework I've ever seen.

Comment: It's not just you.  But keep in mind that large chunks of Express's functionality are built on Connect so check out its documentation too.  http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/

Comment: you can look at the old docs at https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/2.x then viewing the wiki https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is essentially setting up a the middleware used in your express app. A lot of this middleware Is part of the connect middleware framework which express is built on top of. As mentioned by JohnnyHK in the comments, you can find more info on these in the connect documentation.

I agree that there should be more on the express site explaining what is going on, or at least something pointing new users in the right direction to find the info.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was just browsing through the old documentation (pre 3.0.0) and in fact they do explain middleware somewhat. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Good info can often be found in the [Express wiki](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki), as well as their [Code examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples)

If you are still stuck, consider asking in #express on freenode IRC

Answer (score 0):

After some weird google-ing i found their 2.x docs.. No idea why all this invaluable info hasnt been ported yet.

http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html